# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElasticSearchError' : Using Haystack Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, attributeerror

Using Django & Haystack with ElasticSearch.

After installing haystack and ES, and Rebuilding Index

```
./manage.py rebuild_index
```

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

```
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 1039 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10ca3ded0>.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElasticSearchError'
```

Updating index has the same problem

```
/manage.py update_index 
Indexing 1039 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10ea49d90>.
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElasticSearchError'
```

Clear index works fine though ( probably because there is no index )

```
./manage.py clear_index   

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection    'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
```

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.

**Versions**

django-haystack==2.0.0-beta
pyelasticsearch==0.5
elasticsearch==0.20.6

localhost:9200 says :

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Jigsaw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.20.6",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Haystack settings :

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

search_indexes.py :

```
import datetime
import haystack
from haystack import indexes
from app.models import City

class CityIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    state = indexes.CharField(model_attr='state')
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country')
    lat = indexes.FloatField(model_attr='latitude')
    lon = indexes.FloatField(model_attr='longitude')
    alt = indexes.FloatField(model_attr='altitude')
    pop = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='population')

    def get_model(self):
        return City
```

**Any help - why I am getting error ?**

Comment: could you paste a snipped version of your settings and your haystack searchmodels, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it !

After debugging the process  using pdb

```
./manage.py rebuild_index
```

At line 222 - in /haystack/backend/elasticsearch_backend.py

Changed

```
except (requests.RequestException, pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchError), e:
```

To

```
# except (requests.RequestException, pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchError), e:
except Exception as inst:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

I found out the core error was this

```
'ElasticSearch' object has no attribute 'from_python'.
```

To which I found solution here - https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/514#issuecomment-4058230

The version of pyelasticsearch I was using was from http://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch,

So I installed pyelasticsearch from a fork - http://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch using :

```
pip install --upgrade  git+https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch.git@3bfe1a90eab6c2dfb0989047212f4bc9fb814803#egg=pyelasticsearch
```

and That fixed it & Index was build !

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  I originally installed pyelasticsearch through pip.  I removed it and then installed from toastdriven's repo.  Now I run into: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElasticHttpError'".  Any ideas here?

Comment: Hey @Chris,

did you exactly used this - `pip install --upgrade  git+https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch.git@3bfe1a90eab6c2dfb0989047212f4bc9fb814803#egg=pyelasticsearch`. It is a very specific version which worked for me.

Whats happening is pyelasticsearch that is installed, is either not accessible or does not match the version required by ElasticSearch.

Can you share version of :
django-haystack
pyelasticsearch
elasticsearch